# Display row count based on variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, SpeciesHuntBoats contains details of Boats, the Make, Skipper etc. and SpeciesHunt which is generated by the skipper submitting a catch report form with details of their fishing catches. showboats.php displays 5 columns, Year, Boat Name, Make, Skipper, Number Of Species Caught.

For the final column I want a display of the number of rows in SpeciesHunt where that BoatName appears (to give a leaderboard of who has entered the most catches). This is as far as I've been able to get unfortunately, any help much appreciated!

```
<body>

<?php
$servername = "xxx";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Count Rows
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM SpeciesHunt");
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
// Check row count of entire table works
echo "$num_rows Rows\n";


$sql = "SELECT Year, BoatName, BoatMake, Skipper FROM SpeciesHuntBoats";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>Hunt Year</th><th>Boat Name</th><th>Boat Make</th><th>Skipper</th><th>Number Of Species</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["Year"]. "</td><td>" . $row["BoatName"]. "</td><td>" . $row["BoatMake"]. "</td><td>" . $row["Skipper"]. "</td><td>

$num_rows</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>

</body>
```

Table structures:
[SpeciesHunt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgwZ6.png)

[SpeciesHuntBoats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRpST.png)

Comment: Could you post the table structures as well? You could do this in one query that's a bit larger if your table structures are set up correctly.

Comment: Added to original post, thank you. I can easily change the structure if needed

Answer (score 0):

For your tables, you should rather make use of a relationship between boats and hunts

You should research a bit into sql relationships.

Currently you are basically saving the boat name, make and skipper twice.

This is a better suggestion for the structure:

**Boats:**

- Year
- Name
- Make
- Skipper
- Photo

**Hunts:**

- DateCaught
- Angler
- Species
- Notes
- BoatId (This will be a reference to a certain boat record)

In this case you can do a sql query that joins the two tables

```
select Year, Name, Make, Skipper, count(hunts.id) from boats 
join hunts on boats.id = hunts.BoatId
group by Year, Name, Make, Skipper;
```

What this will return is a certain boat with a total count of hunt records.

**Things you can research into:**

- MySQL relationships
- MySQL joins
- MySQL aggregates

Comment: Thank you - year is actually the 'year of the competition' rather than the boat year. Each year we start a new competition where boats will re-register for that year